# Editing css through JavaScript (using calc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to do the following math using JavaScript to edit the css. Here's the calculation I'm trying to do:

```
calc((100% / first) - (second * 2))
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, but it's not working. I tried taking away all the variables, and just have numbers (100%/3), and that worked.

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nf8cy68d/), and here's the actual code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var first = 3;
  var second = 10;

  $("p").css({
    // (100% / first) - (second * 2)
    "width": "calc((100%/" + first + ") - (" + second " * 2))"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p style="background-color:#ff0000">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p style="background-color:#00ff00">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p style="background-color:#0000ff">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: I hope you are aware of the support of [`calc`](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Comment: what is it supposed to do? I ran your jsfiddle with variables and with just numbers and both look the same. Also, if you're updating the css with javascript, why not just do the calculation in javascript?

Comment: The value used for `calc` is not valid, it has to be a simple expression, not multiple expressions with parenthesis. Also, there's a typo, missing a `+`

Comment: So what do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var first = 3;
    var second = 10;
    
    $("p").css({
  // (100% / first) - (second * 2)
        "width": "calc( 100% / " + first + " - " + second + " * 2px)"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>

    <p style="background-color:#ff0000">This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p style="background-color:#00ff00">This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p style="background-color:#0000ff">This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
```